# Return journey of Rama and sand Lingam at Rameswaram

Tags: shiva, ramayana

Query during this Shivarathri ... Did Rama worship Shiva at Rameswaram en route to Ayodhya (on Pushpaka vimanam transit return trip ) after slaying Ravana for Brahma hatya dosham as per Ramayana?...because [Sita also](http://www.rameswaram.com/about.html) is seen pictured here.

Has the sand Siva Lingam survived to the present time? The stone lingam brought by Hanumam naturally would endure.

Comment: This story is mostly found in temple legend books of Rameshwaram and in Puranas like this chapter of Skanda Purana http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/skanda_purana/rameshwar_linga.html ..however few other Puranas and few Ramayanas say that Linga was established while construction of bridge was going on..

Comment: If at bridge construction time Sita should not be there at all.

Comment: Stories vary due to Kalpa bheda.. the picture you provided link for is from the stories in which Linga was established while returning from Lanka...